# Android Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) : Facing issue in token expiry handling, how to refresh token using MSAL Android SDK

Tags: android, azure, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement MSAL in Android for logging in user using their Microsoft credentials.
On clean install, first time I am able to get the token, and use it further for accessing Microsoft Graph API.

As expiry time for MSAL token is 1 hour by default, after 1 hour if I try to re-start the app, I face token authentication exception.

Now I am stuck on how to refresh the token again ?

In MSAL I have followed the examples, but nowhere is there any mention of refreshing a token using Android SDK [we can use API calls otherwise to get and refresh token, but I am not using API approach, I am using SDK for handling all the flow.]

I am trying to get through this for some days now.

```
private val AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
private var mSingleAccountApp: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication? = null
private var mActiveAccount: MultiTenantAccount? = null

fun startTokenProcess(
    activity: LoginActivity,
    preferenceManager: PreferenceManager
) {
    this.mActivity = activity
    this.mPreferences = preferenceManager

    mSingleAccountApp = null

    // Creates a PublicClientApplication object with res/raw/auth_config.json
    PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(activity,
        R.raw.auth_config,
        object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
            override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication?) {

                // initialization of ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication object
                mSingleAccountApp = application

                // check for existence of any account linked in cache
                mSingleAccountApp?.getCurrentAccountAsync(object :
                    ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.CurrentAccountCallback {
                    override fun onAccountLoaded(activeAccount: IAccount?) {

                        if (activeAccount == null) {

                            // nothing found
                            // start new interactive signin
                            mSingleAccountApp?.signIn(mActivity, "", getScopes(),
                                object : AuthenticationCallback {
                                    override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult?) {
                                        mActiveAccount =
                                            authenticationResult?.account as MultiTenantAccount?

                                        // save access token in SP
                                        authenticationResult?.accessToken?.let {
                                            mPreferences.putString(
                                                KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                                it
                                            )
                                        }

                                        callGraphAPI(authenticationResult?.accessToken)
                                    }

                                    override fun onCancel() {
                                        Timber.d("Canceled")
                                    }

                                    override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
                                        Timber.d(exception?.errorCode)
                                    }
                                })
                        } else {
                            // Founded an valid account in cache
                            // get account token from SP, call Graph API
                            // todo: check if access token expired ? ask for new token, clear SP
                            mActiveAccount = activeAccount as MultiTenantAccount?
                            val accessToken = mPreferences.getString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                            if (accessToken != null) {
                               
                                callGraphAPI(accessToken)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onAccountChanged(
                        priorAccount: IAccount?,
                        currentAccount: IAccount?
                    ) {
                        Timber.d("Founded an account $priorAccount")
                        Timber.d("Founded an account $currentAccount")
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
                        Timber.e(exception)
                    }
                })
            }

            override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
                Timber.e(exception)
            }
        })
}
```

I have tried to get token Silently and Interactively again, but no success.

SILENTLY:

```
mSingleAccountApp?.acquireTokenSilentAsync(getScopes(), AUTHORITY, getAuthSilentCallback())

private fun getAuthSilentCallback(): SilentAuthenticationCallback {
    return object : SilentAuthenticationCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult) {
            Timber.d("Successfully authenticated")

            /* Successfully got a token, use it to call a protected resource - MSGraph */
            callGraphAPI(authenticationResult?.accessToken)
        }

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            /* Failed to acquireToken */
            Timber.e("Authentication failed: $exception")
            if (exception is MsalClientException) {
                Timber.e("Exception inside MSAL, more info inside MsalError.java ")
            } else if (exception is MsalServiceException) {
                Timber.e("Exception when communicating with the STS, likely config issue")
            } else if (exception is MsalUiRequiredException) {
                Timber.e("Tokens expired or no session, retry with interactive")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

INTERACTIVELY:

```
if (activeAccount == null) {
mSingleAccountApp?.signIn(mActivity, "", getScopes(),
object : AuthenticationCallback {
    override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult?) {
        mActiveAccount =
            authenticationResult?.account as MultiTenantAccount?

        // save access token in SP
        authenticationResult?.accessToken?.let {
            mPreferences.putString(
                KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                it
            )
        }

        callGraphAPI(authenticationResult?.accessToken)
    }

    override fun onCancel() {
        Timber.d("Canceled")
    }

    override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
        Timber.d(exception?.errorCode)
    }
})
}
```

Edit 1:

Exceptions I am geting:

```
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 414Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken

CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 414Error message: Access token has expired.

CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 414SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.9.0

CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 414Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI[...]

CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 414Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken

Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
    Error message: Access token has expired.
```

When I re-try to get token silently, I get the following exception:

```
l$getAuthSilentCallback: Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'Some_ID' was not found in the directory 'Some_ID'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
    Trace ID: 'Some_ID'
    Correlation ID: 'Some_ID'
    Timestamp: 2020-08-15 06:06:11Z

getAuthSilentCallback: Exception when communicating with the STS, likely config issue
```

Edit 2
As per exceptions I was getting regarding config issue, I got the issue, it was related to the Authority URL which I was using. [msal-client-application-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

**DIAGNOSING**

Are there any error details you can provide? And have you traced the HTTPS token refresh message?

**WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE**

The MSAL library should be sending a Refresh Token Grant message, as in [steps 15 and 16 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/).

My app uses AppAuth libraries but MSAL will work the same way, since that is standard for a mobile app.

Comment: I have added exception logs, today I recreated the same in another new android studio project. Now when I try to get access Graph API silently, I get exception still

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue, it was with the AUTHORITY URL: private val AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", it should have been "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_id]/"

Comment: Pleased to hear you've resolved your problems. It is worth understanding messages used - if you run into further problems my [Azure Post 1](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup/) and [Azure Post 2](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) may give you some ideas.